# Why exporting df to cvs is not exporting second column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, frame

I have a df containing index and a column that is floating numbers and exporting to csv works.
But when i change from floating to integer and then change value of column to 1 for those which value is above 50 and 0 for those below 50 then export to csv fail and only index plust column header is exported.
I've debugged and got to conclusion that the problem is when i entered the '0' values. Up to that point csv export works....
Any hint why that?

Thanks

```
prediction = model.predict(predict_data)
sol = pd.DataFrame(data=prediction, columns=['predicted'])
sol.index.name = 'index'
sol['final_prediction'] = final_sol['predicted'].astype(int)
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] > 50, 'predicted'] = 1
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] == 50, 'predicted'] = 1
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] < 50, 'predicted'] = 0  # this is the point when fail occurs. 
sol.to_csv('export_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sol = pd.DataFrame(data=task, columns=['predicted'])
sol.index.name = 'index'
sol['final_prediction'] = sol['predicted'].astype(int)
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] > 50, 'predicted'] = 1
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] == 50, 'predicted'] = 1
sol.loc[sol['predicted'] < 50, 'predicted'] = 0  # this is the point when fail occurs. 
# print(sol)
sol.to_csv('export_file.csv')
```

I think error on this line `final_sol['predicted'].astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo but not the problem indeed. Still same problem happens and i don't understand which is the effect of converting to 0s making export to csv not working

Comment: I can see the 1s are exported but not the 0s. Why?